# Conditional expectation when minimum is given.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I try to solve this:

> Let $X,Y$ be two independent exponential r.v. with parameters $\mu,\lambda>0$. > Let $T:=\min(X,Y)$ Compute $\mathbb{E}(T\vert X)$

Now there is a hint to compute $\mathbb{E}(Tf(X))$ for some measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ but what confuses me, is that $\min(x,y)$ has two components and is not from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. So I tried to rewrite $$\mathbb{E}(Tf(X))=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Tf(X)\vert X))=\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mathbb{E}(T\vert X))$$ but I don't see whether this is useful or not.

My second attempt was to work with the density. I computed the CDF for $T$ which is $F(t)=1-e^{-t(\lambda + \mu)}$ and the PDF $$f(t)=(\lambda + \mu)e^{-t(\lambda + \mu)}$$

But I'm not sure, if this is useful here.

Comment: If you have the PDF and CDF for $T$, and presumably also the PDF and CDF for $X$ (since $X$ is a generic independent exponential RV), you can use that to compute the PDF and CDF of $\mathbb{E}(T|X)=:\mathbb{E}(T|X=x)$.


For example, see here: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/117   I think the only possible hitch is that you are working with $\min(X,Y)$ rather than $(X,Y)$ itself, but that might be salvageable using the change of variables formula, I'm not sure though, thus why I deleted my answer https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/160

Comment: @William: I think the issue with that approach is that $X$ and $T$ don't have a joint pdf because $\mathbb{P}(X=T)>0$.

Comment: Good opportunuity to get familiar wih indicator functions! So, one looks for some $g$ such that, for every suitable $f$, $$E(Tf(X))=E(g(X)f(X))$$ since then  $E(T\mid X)=g(X)$. The RHS is direct since you know the PDF of $X$. The LHS is $$E(Tf(X);X<Y)+E(Tf(X);X>Y)=E(Xf(X);X<Y)+E(Yf(X);X>Y)$$ and each part of the RHS can be computed as the expectation of a function of $(X,Y)$. That is, $$E(Xf(X);X<Y)=E(Xf(X)e^{-\mu X})=\int_0^\infty xf(x)e^{-\mu x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$ Likewise, $$E(Yf(X);X>Y)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\int_0^xy\mu e^{-\mu y}dydx$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: You do not understand why $E(T\mid X)=g(X)$ for some function $g$?

Comment: @Did no, this I do understand. I don't understand why we use $E(Tf(X))$ (as well why it is mentioned in the hint.)

Comment: Characterization of conditional expectation. Perhaps check a textbook.

Comment: @Did Unfortunately I can't find anything in books and scripts that I searched through that makes a connection between $E(Y\vert X)$ and $E(Yf(X))$. The only thing I see is that $E(f(X,Y)|g(X,Y))=h(g(X,Y))$ for measurable functions. Does this characterization come from calculations with the indicator function?

Comment: Never met the characterization of $E(Y\mid X)$ as the unique $g(X)$ such that $E(Yh(X))=E(g(X)h(X))$ for every $h$? You might want to switch to serious sources then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this question, you can also work it out directly as follows:
\begin{align*}
E(\min(X, Y) \mid X) &=E(X1_{Y\ge X} \mid X) + E(Y1_{X\ge Y} \mid X)\\
&=X \int_X^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy + \int_0^{X}\lambda y e^{-\lambda y} dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(1-e^{-\lambda X} \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: @Gordon
Hey, I just found this question and have a question concerning one of your steps. Why is $E(X1_{Y\ge X} \mid X)=X \int_X^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy$ ? I understand that $E(X1_{Y\ge X} \mid X)=XE(1_{Y\ge X} \mid X)$ but why is $E(1_{Y\ge X} \mid X)=E(1_{Y\ge X})$ as we will have later $E(1_{Y\ge X})=\int_X^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} dy$.

Comment: @PeterGarder: As $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(1_{Y\ge X}\mid X) = E(1_{Y\ge x})\, |_{x=X}$. However, note that $E(1_{Y\ge X}\mid X) \ne E(1_{Y\ge X})$.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you very much for still answering. I guess it takes some time to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Is there a special definition of $E(1_{Y\ge x})\, |_{x=X}$?
Otherwise, what would be the difference to  $E(1_{Y\ge X})$?

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterGarder: The expectation $E(Y≥X)$ takes both $X$ and $Y$ into consideration. However, in $E(Y≥x)\,|_{x=X}$, we take expectation $E(Y≥x)$ by treating $x$ as a constant, and then replace $x$ with $X$.